# How can I run wiring around an inside corner?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am working in a garage and need to run electrical wire through a corner.  I cannot go over the corner through the ceiling (a long story), and going through the studs at a right angle will be a significant challenge.

Since this is a garage, I'm ok if the wire comes out of the sheet rock.  Can I just have the wire come out through the sheetrock, in a conduit, go around the corner, and then have it go back into the second wall?

Or must the wire go to a box on the first wall, come out of the box in a conduit, then go into a box on the second wall and then continue on?

---

Thanks for the repliess -  I think the trunking is the way to go.  I just don't know if I need to have an electrical box on each wall at the exit and entry points (?) or can I just come in and out directly, assuming the wire is within the trunk while outside the wall?...

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-6-ft-3-4-in-Liquaflex-NM-Whip-Kit-58004609/203424766

Comment: Is there sheetrock in place now?  If there is, do you mind tearing some off to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues with drilling the corner, realize that you can make the job significantly more possible with an ordinary drill if you don't try to hold it level - shift the wire up or down a few inches as well as taking it around the corner, and the hole becomes much easier to drill.

As for your question about the approach using conduit, that's going to depend on the LAHJ (local authority having jurisdiction) a.k.a. "the building inspector", if you are subject to inspection. Generally better to ask them first, than to try and convince them that the internet said X would be OK...what is acceptable in one local area may not be in another, and in some cases what's acceptable in the same area will vary with inspector (probably shouldn't, but often does, even so.)

Answer (score 0):

Just use same trunking if it is somewhere is will not get damaged, otherwise use metal conduit.

There is no need to run a cable in a wall apart from trying to hide it, provided you give the cable enough protection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered running the wire down to the baseboard, temporarily removing it, then running the wire just above the sole plate, around the corner, and to up to your destination. Removing and re-installing baseboard in a garage would be quick and easy because you don't have to be too fussy about it. At the corner I would make a notch, lay in the cable, and use a nail-plate (example below) to protect the wire.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you **run `BX cable` instead of `ROMEX`** it won't matter if it's inside or outside of the wall. If you run the entire length outside the wallm, the time you will save on installation generally offsets the cost of the cable.